# Was ist eigentlich der Unterschied zwischen Kabarett und Comedy?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-case

> Der Comedian macht es wegen dem Geld, der Kabarettist macht es wegen
>   des Geldes.

Was ist mit diesem Witz genau gemeint? Ich verstehe es nicht.

Comment: Um das ganze noch komplizierter zu machen: Es gibt auch noch den Begriff der [_Satire_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satire), die ähnlich wie Kabarett meist (gesellschafts)politische Ziele hat und auf witzige Weise (z.B. mit Übertreibung) Inhalte [parodiert](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parodie). Heutzutage wird Kabarett oft als etwas “altmodisches” gesehen und Satire v.a. ist v.a. durch (politische) Satiresendungen bekannt. Man muss aber natürlich sagen, dass auch hier die Grenzen schwimmend, also nicht scharf, sind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Der Comedian macht es wegen **dem** Geld, der Kabarettist macht es wegen **des** Geldes.

Jetzt klarer? Der Comedian wendet sich an ein "weniger gebildetes" Publikum, dem es egal ist, ob nun Dativ oder Genitiv benutzt wird. Es geht aber noch eine Spur gebildeter:

> Der Comedian macht es wegen **dem** Geld, der Kabarettist macht es **des Geldes wegen**.

Mit so einem Spruch kann man vor einem Publikum aus Studienräten glänzen, wie man es im Kabarett vorfindet.

Comment: "Der Dativ ist dem Genetiv sein tot" schlägt wohl in die gleiche Richtung. Wobei hier wohl die Grenze zwischen Comedian und Kabarettist verschwimmt.

Comment: Dann gehöre ich in die Gruppe Comedian ;-) Danke Dir

Comment: Dem Comedian sein Sprachgebrauch ist halt nicht für alle so erquicklich.- Aber jetzt mal ernst: Ich denke nicht, dass der Unterschied primär im Publikum liegt. Vielmehr liegt er in der künstlerischen Absicht: Der Comedian will einfach nur lustig sein. Der Kabarettist will lustig sein, aber vor allem auch eine gesellschaftlich-politische Botschaft vermitteln. Dass in der Folge dann auch das Publikum ein bisschen unterschiedlich ist: Ja, dem Argument seine Kraft kann man nicht verleugnen.

Comment: Beide wollen Geld verdienen. Der Kabarettist, der diese Pointe bringt, hat sich ein schwieriges Publikum rausgesucht, das der Comedian nicht bedienen kann, weil die Scherze nicht ziseliert genug sind. Umgekehrt kann er aber auch keine Hallen füllen, den so viele Studienräte gibt's halt auch wieder nicht.

Comment: @Janka  Ich mag Kabarett mehr als Comedy, und doch bin ich kein Studienrat. Mache ich was fasch?

Comment: Volker Pispers zieht bei seinen Auftritten jedenfalls grundsätzlich über Lehrer her, in der festen Annahme, dass genügend davon im Publikum sind.

Comment: "Der Dativ ist dem Genetiv sein Tod.", oder?

Comment: Der Spruch macht sich in doppelter Weise über Kabarettisten lustig, und letztlich auch über ihr Publikum, das an bildungsbürgerlichen Sprachnormen festhalte und einen höheren Anspruch suche, obwohl es doch da auch nur ums Geldverdienen gehe. Dass sich der Spruch in erster Linie an ein Kabarettpublikum wendet, finde ich überhaupt nicht.

Answer (score 5):

Zu erwähnen ist auch, dass Cabaret und Kabarett zwei verschiedene Dinge sind, und dass zu allem Überfluss in Österreich beide Wörter gleich ausgesprochen werden (nämlich: [kabaˈʁeː] also am Ende mit langem E und ohne T), während weiter im Norden Kabarett als [kabaˈʁɛt] (mit kurzem E und ziemlich knackigem T) ausgesprochen wird.

<sup>So gibt z.B. eine kleines, aber sehr einflussreiches Kabarettlokal in Wien, das [Kabarett Niedermayer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabarett_Niedermair), das als [kabaˈʁeː ˈniːdɐˌmaɪ̯ɐ] ausgesprochen wird.</sup>

- **Cabaret**
  Musiktheater, Revue mit Tanz, meist reine Unterhaltung ohne politische oder gesellschaftskritische Zielsetzung.
  Beim Cabaret stehen meist mehrere (mehr als 5) Tänzerinnen und Tänzer auf der Bühne.
- **Kabarett**
  Kleinkunst, Satire, oft (nicht immer) gesellschaftskritisch. Musik kann darin vorkommen, hat aber eine untergeordnete Rolle.
  Beim Kabarett steht oft nur ein einzelner Kabarettist auf der Bühne, auch kleine Gruppen mit weniger als 5 Personen gibt es.
- **Comedy**
  Unterhaltungstheater, das meist von einer einzelnen Person vorgetragen wird und keine gesellschaftskritische oder politische Zielsetzung hat.

Comment: Der Beibehalt der französichen Aussprache von Kabarett (trotz eingedeutscher Schreibung) in Österreich ist spannend! Wie sagt ihr zu einem Kabarettisten?

Comment: @Takkat: Zu einem Kabarettisten sagen wir »Kabarettist«. Die Aussprache ist [kabaʁɛˈtɪst], und ich vermute, so wird das Wort auch sonst überall genau so ausgesprochen.

Comment: Auch das ist interessant. Ich war unsiche oder hätte gedacht, dass es dann der *Kabarettier* wäre.

Answer (score 4):

Der Übergang zwischen beiden Genres ist fließend. Der Witz bezieht sich darauf, dass der Genuss einer Comedy Veranstaltung nicht notwendigerweise Vorwissen erfordert. Hier geht es in erster Linie, um Belustigung, Bespaßung.

Im Gegensatz dazu bietet eine Kabarett-Veranstaltung auch weitere Bedeutungs-Ebenen und kann z.B. Gesellschaftskritik oder politische Satire beinhalten. Diese Bedeutung erschließt sich aber, je nach Thematik nur mit dem entsprechenden Vorwissen.

Der Witz zieht aus diesem Unterschied den Rückschluss darauf, dass das Publikum (und der Künstler) einer Comedy-Veranstaltung niedrigeren Anspruch hat, als das einer Kabarett-Veranstaltung. Und erweitert diesen Schluss auf den Gebrauch der Sprache, indem dem Comedy-Teil ein (geläufiger) Grammatik-Fehler untergeschoben wird, während der Kabarett-Teil eine korrektere und gehobenere Ausdrucksweise verwendet.

Wenn man aber von dieser äußeren Form absieht, so liegt beiden Sätzen (offensichtlich) dieselbe Bedeutung zu Grunde. Der zweite Witz ist also, dass beide Humor-Formen sich eigentlich auch nur der Gage unterordnen. Auch dieser Witz ist also sowohl Comedy (haha, er hat einen Grammatik-Fehler gemacht), als auch (einfache) Satire (Kunst, braucht Geld) und legt damit offen, dass diese Trennung vielleicht garnicht soviel Sinn macht.;)

Answer (score 2):

Comedy ist Kabarett ohne Nachdenken.

Answer (score -4):

Der Comedian macht es wegen dem Geld,
der Kabarettist macht es wegen des Geldes.

Es geht hier einfach um den Unterschied deutsch - österreichisch!
Die Österreicher lieben es die Deutschen zu verarschen & das ist so ein typischer "haha die Deutschen Witz"... da geht es nicht darum wer wie ach so sehr gebildet ist oder nicht, oder um sonst irgendetwas anderes!
Österreicher verwenden (noch) den Genitiv & für einen Österreicher gibt es in Deutschland mal sowieso keinen Kabarettisten.

Comment: Herzlich Wilkommen. Ist dein Beitrag wirklich eine Antwort, oder vielleicht doch eher ein Kommentar? Vielleicht willst du hier mal vorbeischauen: https://german.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Das muss man dann aber wohl dazuschreiben, dass es ein Witz gegen die Piefkes sein soll. So ausgestorben ist der Genitiv im Deutschen ja nicht.

Comment: Hallo Ossi, und willkommen auf german.SE! Kannst du genauer erklären, inwiefern das ein Witz über Deutsche ist, oder inwiefern das in Österreich als ein Witz über Deutsche wahrgenommen wird? Das würde deine Antwort sicher verbessern.

Comment: Der Witz ist von Volker Pispers, und der kommt aus Düsseldorf.